# PHP Debug-class leaking artifacts on the webpage

Tags: php

I have this Debug class

```
class Debug {       
    static function log($string){
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $string."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

And im using it to dump some stuff to my debug file.

For example, i have this code:

```
    public function getActiveLocks($ship){

        Debug::log("EW for ship #".$ship->id); //$ship->id = 1 

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->ships); $i++){    
            $target = $this->ships[$i]->getCurrentPosition();
            $dist = Math::getDist2($pos, $target);

            if ($dist <= $ew->dist){
                Debug::log("potential lock vs: #".$this->ships[$i]->id);
            }
            else {
                Debug::log("no lock vs: #".$this->ships[$i]->id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which has, as you notice, 3 calls to `Debug::log`.
Now, the logging does happen correctly.
However, occasionally the class is apparently leaking HTML into the document body. In that specific example above, the very `Debug::log` call results in my webpage displaying "))" in the body (in addition to properly writing into the log file).

If i delete the **first** entry, my HTML will be displayed just fine.
Deleing the second or third entry wont delete the leaking "))".
So, for some reason, the very first `Debug::log` call (which is called once!). results in echoing )). I dont know why or how, but its a major annoyance that i cant figure out. Also, its breaking my scriping at times.

Please note i left some variables out to just show the base problem im facing. Im certain i didnt leave anything important out.

Please advice.

Comment: The flaw is not in this code. Please check your source file for `))`.

Comment: Can you expand on that ? I cant see how something different can be the cause, when in fact deleting the like 2 in the function above gets rids of the )). Can you be more specific ?

Comment: In your `php.ini` file, make sure `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`.  Run the code again and see if there are any error messages.  Also, two things to try are: (1) insert `var_dump($ship);` just before the offending `Debug::log` call to see what type `$ship->id` really is.  I suspect it might not be an integer.  And (2) execute this simplified code `$id = 1; Debug::log("EW for ship #".$id);` to see if the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I assume you're using autoloading (via composer of otherwise). That means that the `Debug` class is loaded on first use. I don't know where the `))` is coming from, but I **do** know it's not caused by the code you've posted here.